# Not able to find elements of a sfdc login screen using UIautomater

Tags: mobilesdk, ui, test-automation, salesforce-mobile-app

We have created native Android mobile App using **'com.salesforce.mobilesdk:SalesforceSDK:8.+'** mobile sdk for the login functionality in the app. We use the Community url for login.

We are trying to automate login screen of the app using **Appium**.  We are not able to take a screenshot of sfdc login screen using Uiautomater as sdk blocks the screen capturing due to which we are not able to find the UI elements of the login screen.

**We are using the below tools used
1.Appium -- version:'6.0.0' -- For Automation
2.Uiautomater -- for Finding elements on the screen**

Please help us to find a solution to automate the SFDC login screen displayed in the mobile sdk.